# Clarification needed on LFSR and MISR

Tags: digital-logic, lfsr

I’m attempting a question that involves a three stage LFSR and MISR with a CUT. I’ve been trying to solve for 3 hours straight now, I couldn’t confirm my solution; meaning, i don’t know wether it’s right or not, I’ve scarped textbooks related to this and other materials but I didn’t find any similar question.

Picture:
[image: Problem image]
LFSR and MISR circuit design respectively:
[image: LFSR and MISR Logic]

Attempted solution:
[image]

Comment: Homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: @VoltageSpike There seems to be a solution attempt, the question was edited an hour earlier than your closure. Why did you close actually?

Comment: @VoltageSpike I’ve already attempted the question, and it’s written in my post. Why was it closed?

Comment: @alQahtani Your question is not quite clear, what (kind of) answer do you expect? You have shown a solution, but you say "_I couldn’t confirm my solution_". What is the concrete issue? Isn't the provided solution your own?

Comment: It looked like the OP was asking for something else, I have reopened the question.

Comment: @thebusybee The provided solution is my own, but I’m not sure about it. That is because I couldn’t find a similar question on my textbook and there seems to be an inconsistency between my solution and my friend’s solutions. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Then it is necessary to show both solutions and to [edit] your question adding your specific doubts. A solution is correct, if it fulfils the requirements. Does your solution work correct?

Comment: Please indicate operator precedence in `A⊕B+C` using parentheses.

Comment: What is the difficulty in checking your solution? You do know how to create a truth table of your solution, don't you? So please [edit] your question and add the truth table of your solution. And as I wrote, we are still missing your friend's solution that you compare. Again, I suggest to add the equations or schematic and truth table.

Comment: Check the table entries for X -  find neither (A⊕B)+C nor A⊕(B+C) to fit.

Comment: @greybeard OR precedes XORs.

Comment: @thebusybee Please either ask a real question regarding the question provided, try to answer it (provide feedback) and that would be appreciated or just stop commenting about absolutely unnecessary things that aren’t needed to answer this question. I will not attempt to post a solution that isn’t mine (my friends’), the schematic and truth tables are unnecessary (my final answer was provided in the question).

Comment: Actually you have not posted a question. A question consists of a certain sequence of words ending with a question mark. There are only statements in your prose.

Comment: Well, your post is not that clear. So I misread it, thinking that the equations are your solution for the truth table below. But it is the other way around. Sorry. Anyway, my comment still points in the right direction to help you _learn something_. And this is the actual goal of the task.

Comment: If there is "_an inconsistency between my solution and my friend’s solutions_", we need to see that other solution to take it into account. Additionally it is helpful for us to help you to know details about this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

I can **confirm** that your solution is **not right**.

The truth tables of the equations compared to your solution prove this.

If I assume that OR has precedence over XOR (`X = A ⊕ (B + C)`):

| A | B | C | expected X | expected Y | expected Z | your X | your Y | your Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | -> ***0*** | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | -> ***1*** | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

If I assume that XOR has precedence over OR (`X = (A ⊕ B) + C`):

| A | B | C | expected X | expected Y | expected Z | your X | your Y | your Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | -> ***1*** | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | -> ***1*** | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The emphasized values are not what is expected.

The consequences to the MISR are left as an exercise...

---

*Note: From your comment this seems to be what you want. Feel free to edit your question if you want something else.*

Comment: @greybeard Actually, the first table is for `A⊕(B+C)`; now extended to both variants.